# Returning local reference

Tags: c++, reference

When I run my code, attempting to return a local variable:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int &fun()
{     
  int x = 30;      
  return x;    
}

int main()    
{   
    fun() = 10;   
    cout << fun();    
    return 0;    
}
```

why does some compiler output 0 and some are 30

Comment: define _some_ compiler.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour

Comment: gcc , ideone geeks4geeks ide

Comment: i would say it is very ugly code. what is the use-case?
apart from that, you may want to use `static int x = 30;`.

Comment: Voted to reopen: duplicate is the pointer case.

Comment: @Bathsheba please find more appropriate duplicate then, because there must be some.

Answer (score 3):

Returning a reference to a local variable that subsequently goes out of scope is undefined behaviour in C++.

Sometimes it might work, sometimes it might not. Occasionally the compiler might eat your cat.

Comment: I always knew computers ran on kitties and bits.